# How to check the process progress using background worker

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a method that use in downloading files from server . MY method works fine, however i want to return a calculated percentage of the process execute at each instance of the execution. i tried to use backgroundworker and use the backgroundworker_changed method for my progressbar as below.

```
  bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

Start worker on button click.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                if (bw.IsBusy != true)
                {

                    bw.RunWorkerAsync();

                }

        }
```

worker_changed method

```
 private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = e.ProcessPercentage;
        }
```

My problem is , i understand i have to report progress from the DoWork() method. Please how do i achieve that? I thought of doing something like this.

```
  private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32( e.UserState );

        }
```

It still does not fire as there was no progress returned from the DoWork. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to call the BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress method from your bw_DoWork method

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ReportProgress` from your `DoWork` method along with the precentage int value.

For example:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     //you can safely pass data out of the thread via the 'obj'
     bw.ReportProgress(0, obj); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [official tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) from msdn. You have to report progress changes by yourself inside your `DoWork` method. Here's is an example :

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    worker.ReportProgress(10/*the percentage you want*/);
}
```

The `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event :

> is raised when you call the ReportProgress method

and it is designed to :

> add code to indicate the progress, such as updating the user
>   interface.

The `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event :

> occurs when the background operation has completed, has been canceled,
>   or has raised an exception

Both events are intended to be called when your `DoWork` method failed, ended or called the `ReportProgress` method. So in another words, we can say that you're the one deciding when they occur. It cannot be done without an action of yours, it's your process and only you know when it is 20%, 30%or 100% (and so on...) completed.